# Why QCoreApplication::processEvents() blocks QThread::wait()?

Tags: multithreading, qt, events

I have simple app with two threads: mainThread and one for heavy calculations.

MainWindow ( mainThread ):

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    thread = new QThread(this);
    worker = new Worker;

    connect(this, &MainWindow::start, worker, &Worker::calculate);

    worker->moveToThread(thread);

    thread->start();

    emit start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    thread->quit();

    qInfo()<<"BEFORE WAIT";
    thread->wait();
    qInfo()<<"AFTER WAIT";

    delete ui;
}
```

The secondThread ( heavy calculations ):

```
void Worker::calculate()
{
    double z = 21;

    for(int i=0;i<100000000;i++)
    {
        if(i%10000000 == 0) // only to show, the second thread works
        {
            qDebug()<<i;
        }

        z+=qSin(i*0.32)*qCos(i/2*0.31); // heavy calculations
        z+=1000/(i+1);
    }

    qDebug()<<"END";
}
```

When I close app using X button and calculations are in progress, everything is ok. In mainThread I wait on `thread->wait()` and when the second thread ends work - app is closed.

Now I add only one line to my code:

```
void Worker::calculate()
{
    double z = 21;

    for(int i=0;i<100000000;i++)
    {
        if(i%10000000 == 0)
        {
            qDebug()<<i;
        }

        z+=qSin(i*0.32)*qCos(i/2*0.31);
        z+=1000/(i+1);
    }

    QCoreApplication::processEvents();  // new Line
    qDebug()<<"END";
}
```

I do the same: close app using X button, when calculations are in progress. I wait on `thread->wait()`, I see on debuq `END`, but my app is not closed - I still wait on `thread->wait()`. Why QCoreApplication::processEvents() blocks QThread::wait(), when QThread finished work?

EDIT:

Full code of my App:

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MainWindow mw;
  mw.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

mainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    thread = new QThread(this);
    worker = new Worker;

    connect(this, &MainWindow::start, worker, &Worker::calculate);

    worker->moveToThread(thread);

    thread->start();

    emit start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    thread->quit();

    qInfo()<<"BEFORE WAIT";
    thread->wait();
    qInfo()<<"AFTER WAIT";

    delete ui;
}
```

mainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QThread>
#include <worker.h>
#include <QDebug>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QThread *thread;
    Worker *worker;

signals:
    void start();
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

worker.h:

```
#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtMath>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

class Worker: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker();
public slots:
    void calculate();
};

#endif // WORKER_H
```

worker.cpp

```
#include "worker.h"

Worker::Worker()
{

}

void Worker::calculate()
{
    double z = 21;

    for(long long i=0;i<10000000000;i++)
    {
        if(i%10000000 == 0) // only to show, the second thread works
        {
            qDebug()<<i;
        }

        z+=qSin(i*0.32)*qCos(i/2*0.31); // heavy calculations
        z+=1000/(i+1);
    }

    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    qDebug()<<"END";
}
```

.pro

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp \
    worker.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h \
    worker.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Comment: Your use of QThread is completely wrong. You cannot call application's `processEvents()` from another thread. It just does not work like that. You can only call mthods of a QObject from the thread in which the QObject lives (well, there are a few exceptional usecases to this rule, but they are definitely not your case). Btw. what is this call to `processEvets()` supposed to actually do? What events should it process? And why?

Comment: @V.K. In my example ```processEvents()``` no make sense. I know it. There are no events to process. This is simple app, only to show my problem. I can execute that method in any thread. I execute it on my second thread ( no make real sense ) and I see BUG. There is on windows 10 QT 5.15.1. I check on linux 5.9 and here everything is fine.

Comment: There is no BUG. `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` is not supposed to be called from other than main thread.

Comment: @V.K. Not sure I follow.  Where did you read that `"QCoreApplication::processEvents() is not supposed to be called from other than main thread"` ?

Comment: OK, my mistake. `processEvents()` is marked as-thread safe so it probably should be OK to call it from another thread.

Comment: I was experimenting with the example a bit and I can confirm this strange behavior. I also found that if you use `connect(thread, &QThread::started, worker, &Worker::calculate);` instead of your version of `connect(...)`, then it works as expected. But I have no idea why. We need someone more knowledgeable.

Comment: Actually, @V.K. makes a good point re. the use of `QThread::started` vs `MainWindow::start` signals.  Can you show the complete code for the `Worker` class?

Comment: @G.M. I used the simplest `Worker` class possible... it has only the implementation of `calculate()` as shown above, nothing else. It inherits `QObject`.

Comment: @V.K. Sorry, my comment was actually for the OP -- I just pinged you to ack. your comment.  Let me ping the OP directly.

Comment: @juga92 Please edit your question to show the complete code for the `Worker` class.

Comment: @G.M. I added full code

Comment: @V.K. I added full code